# Change Angular input placeholder text size?

Tags: css, angular, typescript, angular-material

I have an input like this:

```
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width" floatLabel="always">
    <mat-label>Código de expediente</mat-label>
    <input type="string" placeholder="Código de expediente" [formControl]="codExp" matInput>
</mat-form-field>
```

The result is as following:

[image]

> How can I make the placeholder text smaller?

Note that `label` is always floated, and I need to change the `placeholder` font size

Answer (score 4):

If you would like to customise your Angular material components and provide your own stylings for the `mat-input` placeholder, I have the following suggestions.

1) Overwrite the classes on your main style.css (or style.scss, whichever you are using). If you are wondering, it is the one that is on the same directory level as your index.html, main.ts, package.json, etc.

```
.mat-form-field-label {
  font-size: 0.8em!important;
}
```

I have created a demo over [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gsykrh?file=styles.css).

2) Use `ViewEncapsulation:None`. In my opinion, this is not-so-recommended, as it removes all forms of styles encapsulation on your component, such that CSS rules will have a global effect.

On your `component.ts`, you will need to import `ViewEncapsulation`, followed by selecting `None` when you provide the definitions for encapsulation.

```
import { Component, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'input-overview-example',
  styleUrls: ['input-overview-example.css'],
  templateUrl: 'input-overview-example.html',
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

You can define your CSS styles on your component's css, 
, but without the `!important` declaration.

```
.mat-form-field-label {
  font-size: 0.8em;
}
```

I have created another demo over [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gsykrh-up14qt?file=app/input-overview-example.css).

3) Use the `:host ::ng-deep` pseudo selectors within the same component's css. Doing so will allow you to disable view-encapsulation for that particular rule. Do note that this usage might be risky, as it might be [deprecated](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep) in the future.

On your component's css,

```
:host ::ng-deep .mat-form-field-label {
  font-size: 0.8em;
}
```

I have created another [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gsykrh-jcsp4o?file=app/input-overview-example.css) over here.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `font-size` CSS properties on your input field to define a specific size.

```
input {
    font-size: 0.8em;
}
```

This property will apply on your placeholder, but also the text in the input. To only apply the placeholder you can use the selector [`:empty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:empty)

```
input:empty {
    font-size: 0.8em;
}
```

An alternative is to use `:placeholder`, but this last one [is not compatible with IE11](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-placeholder) so that is something you need to think about.

Answer (score 1):

Use the CSS Selector [`::placeholder`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_placeholder.asp).

```css
input::placeholder {
  font-size: 6px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="" placeholder="small text">
```

Answer (score 1):

try this one with css:

```
input::placeholder { font-size: XXem; }
```

Should help :)

Comment: `:palceholder` is awesome , but not compatible IE11 so I guess worth mentioning. https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-placeholder